# Retrieving join table attribute from model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

So I have a Lessons, Users, and Progresses model as below. I'm trying to display "true" if a user marks a lesson as completed (on the lesson show page, eventually index for each lesson as well). Right now I just want to get the base working and as such have set attributes in console. User 1 has many progresses, and the query is meant to find one that matches the current lesson id and current_user id. I had gotten so far that everything ran but current_user can't be seen from the model. I read that it needs to be passed from the controller. But the controller now gives a undefined method `completed' error. Ive gone around reading railsguides and other SO questions but don't seem to be getting something here. Still a beginner so any help/suggestions are appreciated. Also, as such, if this is a roundabout/bad way of doing it, please tell me the more accepted/rails way.

lesson.rb (.first is only to exclude the others I've experimented with)

```
has_many :progresses
has_many :users, :through => :progresses
def completed(user)
    self.progresses.where("lesson_id = self.id AND user_id = user.id}").first.completed
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :progresses
has_many :lessons, :through => :progresses
```

progress.rb (has user_id, lesson_id, completed:boolean)

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :lesson
```

And the lessons_controller.rb

```
def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    Lesson.completed(current_user) #Trying to make current_user available to model
end
```

lessons#show

```
<%= @lesson.completed %>
```

Comment: call completed on `@lesson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call completed on @lesson like `@lesson.completed(current_user)` currently u r calling it on Lesson class if u want to do that make completed a class method
by adding self to completed

`def self.completed(user)
    self.progresses.where(:user_id => user.id).first.completed
end`

then u can write

`Lesson.completed(current_user)`

Comment: I called completed on @lesson and get "ERROR: syntax error at or near "." " (It seems to be the '.' in current_user.id). I also removed the lesson_id part of the query, as I think that was redundant (the errors show it ran the whole query on top of already knowing the lesson id). Any more ideas? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I adjusted the query to (:user_id = current_user.id) and the error is now "syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end" on the '@lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])' line.

Comment: check value of params[:id], try printing it and `Lesson.find_by_id(params[:id])`

Comment: I changed the query to .where(:user_Id => user.id) and passed user as a param in the show <%= @lesson.completed(current_user) %> and it worked. Is this an OK way to go about it? Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: why u was trying `current_user` in model, u can't access current_user in model..yep you can use like that..cool it work for you